# Checking if shared folder exists using CMD

Tags: network-share, batch, windows-command-prompt

How I could check if network folder shared exists using batch script?

Example: \\10.10.10.1\folder1\folder2\shared_folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if exist  \\10.10.10.1\folder1\folder2\shared_folder echo It's here`

Comment: Okey, I will try adn give you feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

A another option that will keep your script from hanging on a down system:

```
 ping -n 1 %1 >nul && if exist \\10.10.10.1\folder1\folder2\shared_folder echo It's here
```